# Combining binomial and normal values into one significance test?

Tags: statistical-significance, binomial-distribution

I have conducted an experiment in which a participant completes memory tasks (3 levels, within) while exploring a virtual environment (2 levels, within). The performance on these memory tasks is considered a binomial dependent variable. In fact there are two learning periods, each with its own memory task. After exploring the environment in these two learning periods, the participant is asked to find the shortest paths to various landmarks in the environment. We usually consider this success rate as a normally-distributed dependent variable, because we look at the percentage correct out of several path judgments combined into a single measure.

The overall questions driving the experiment are:

1. Does learning such an environment (they are unusual) interfere with memory performance?
2. Does a memory task hinder learning of the environment such that subsequent shortest-path performance will be worse?

Thus far I have done a separate analysis on each dependent variable. Is it possible to somehow (in a statistically valid manner) combine these two scores (actually 3, considering that there are two memory scores to each shortest path result) into a single significance test?

Please let me know if you need clarification on the design.

Comment: Are you estimating a common parameter, or are we in the "[combining independent significance tests](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2281130)" type territory?

Comment: The latter fails for one important reason. I wouldn't expect these tests to be independent. A tradeoff may exist between performance on a memory task and the concurrent map-learning task. Participants may sacrifice on one or the other, if competition exists.

I'm hesitant to say it's a common parameter because it only exists in my imagination, but maybe that's what this is. Perhaps I could create a combined metric of some sort and call it "competition." Is this what you are thinking? If I did this, how would I do it in a statistically valid manner?

Comment: *Is this what you are thinking?* -- for me to be thinking anything in particular, I'd have to understand more than I do about what's going on. But if there is something you're trying to measure and you can articulate how it relates to what you have, there may be a way to do something.

Comment: What would be optimal for me is if I could take these two dependent variables, which I have already done significance tests on, and somehow combine them into one variable. In some cases such a combination may be straightforward, but in my case both variables measure completely different things (memory task correctness and path correctness). Together they tell a story, but they aren't equivalent measures so I don't know how to merge them into a statistically valid entity.

Comment: something like principal components on standardized variables, maybe?